# How to get all siblings in SQL, know one child id I want to get all rows that have the same parent id

Tags: sql

I have a "parent sector" that have "children sectors". This is done in practice using a table sector that have and id_sector and id_parent columns.

I can make a self join as expected. My situation is as follow I have an object that represents a "child sector".

I want to write a query that returns all children sectors with the same parent as of that object id_sector. Is there a simple way to do this, desirably in the join. I am using an ORM and a complex query wouldn't help much because I would have to translate it to suite the ORM.

```
sector             object        
id_sector           id_sector 
id_parent           name
name
```

The object has a sector id

Comment: Are you referring to link list? it is better to put your table structure as well.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: If your ORM cannot handle complex queries, consider changing ORM.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: This is a little confusing because to write SQL you will want to have information about tables and fields, but you are talking about sectors and objects. Also if you have to translate it back into ORM (whatever that means) i'm not sure if having the SQL will do you much good, since in the end it seems you won't be using SQL after all.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a sub-query to find the parent secteur of our record. We then return all secteurs having the same parent secteur.

> ```
> create table t(id_secteur int, id_parent int);
> insert into t values(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from t where id_parent = (select id_parent from t where id_secteur = 1);
> ```

> ```
> id_secteur | id_parent
> ---------: | --------:
>          1 |         1
>          2 |         1
>          3 |         1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9eaac21691ba783eb90089e904e44fd)*